# Finding the answer to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system of nonlinear differential equations:
\begin{cases} \dot{x} = -y-xy \\ \dot{y}= x + x^2, \end{cases} a transformation into polar coordinates of this system can be shown to equal:
 \begin{cases} \dot{\rho} = 0 \\ \dot{\varphi} = 1 + \rho \cos \varphi .\end{cases} 
Suppose the initial values are given as:

\begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix}
 x(0) \\
y(0)
          \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
          2 \\
0
          \end{pmatrix}.
  \end{align}
From this I have calculated that $\varphi(0)=\pi$ and $\rho(0)=2$.
My question is as follows: how can I find the solution to $\varphi(t)$ knowing that $\rho(t)=2$ (as seen from the fact that the differential equation of $\rho$ is 0 and therefore a constant)? In addition, how can I find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ after I know what $\varphi(t)$ and $\rho(t)$ are?

Comment: You are now simply solving a linear differential equation for $\phi(t)$ where you can replace $\rho$. This is a limit cycle solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $\rho=2$, you have
$$ \frac{d\phi}{1+2\cos\phi}=dt$$
and hence
$$ \int\frac{d\phi}{1+2\cos\phi}=t+C_1$$
or
$$ \int\frac{d\phi}{1+2\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\phi}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{\phi}{2}}}=t+C_1$$
By letting $\phi=2\arctan u$, one has $d\phi=\frac{2}{1+u^2}du$ and hence
$$ \int\frac{2}{1+2\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\frac1{1+u^2}du=t+C_1$$
or
$$ \int\frac{2}{3-u^2}du=t+C_1$$
or
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\text{arctanh} \frac{u}{\sqrt3}=t+C_1$$
So
$$ u=\sqrt3\tanh(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t+C_1)$$
and hence
$$ \phi=2\arctan\left[\sqrt3\tanh(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}t+C_1)\right]$$

Comment: The `devil is in the detail`.

Comment: @Chinny84, let $\phi=2\arctan u$ and you will get it.

Comment: I was joking :). But ok you completed the solution!

Comment: I was struggling with solving this equation, thank you for completing your solution and your earlier tip.